# How can I access data from one js file to another?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I access this data in my js file?
(I just pasted a snippet of the js file, but need to access every single country)

Ive added this to my html file

(JS containing my data for countries)

1.script src="js/a4-country-data.js">

(JS I am working on, that needs to access country data)

2.script src="js/myscript.js">

```
ar countries = [

  {
    "Code": "AF",
    "Continent": "Asia",
    "AreaInKm2": 652230,
    "Population": 35530081,
    "Capital": "Kabul",
    "Name": {
      "English": "Afghanistan",
      "Arabic": "أفغانستان",
      "Chinese": "阿富汗",
      "Franch": "Afghanistan",
      "Hindi": "अफ़ग़ानिस्तान",
      "Korean": "아프가니스탄",
      "Japanese": "アフガニスタン",
      "Russian": "Афганистан"
    }
  },
  {
    "Code": "AL",
    "Continent": "Europe",
    "AreaInKm2": 28748,
    "Population": 2930187,
    "Capital": "Tirana",
    "Name": {
      "English": "Albania",
      "Arabic": "ألبانيا",
      "Chinese": "阿尔巴尼亚",
      "Franch": "Albanie",
      "Hindi": "अल्बानिया",
      "Korean": "알바니아",
      "Japanese": "アルバニア",
      "Russian": "Албания"
    }
  },
  {
    "Code": "DZ",
    "Continent": "Africa",
    "AreaInKm2": 2381741,
    "Population": 41318142,
    "Capital": "Algiers",
    "Name": {
      "English": "Algeria",
      "Arabic": "الجزائر",
      "Chinese": "阿尔及利亚",
      "Franch": "Algérie",
      "Hindi": "एलजीरिया",
      "Korean": "알제리",
      "Japanese": "アルジェリア",
      "Russian": "Алжир"
    }
  }
```

into my second js file

```
function populateRow(row,i){
     row.appendChild(getTdElement(countries[i].Continent));

 }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you have. It will do exactly what you ask. It isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: (Well, aside from the `v` missing at the start of `var`, but I assume that is a copy/paste error)

Answer (score 0):

```js
//array.js
var countries = [

  {
    "Code": "AF",
    "Continent": "Asia",
    "AreaInKm2": 652230,
    "Population": 35530081,
    "Capital": "Kabul",
    "Name": {
      "English": "Afghanistan",
      "Arabic": "أفغانستان",
      "Chinese": "阿富汗",
      "Franch": "Afghanistan",
      "Hindi": "अफ़ग़ानिस्तान",
      "Korean": "아프가니스탄",
      "Japanese": "アフガニスタン",
      "Russian": "Афганистан"
    }
  },
  {
    "Code": "AL",
    "Continent": "Europe",
    "AreaInKm2": 28748,
    "Population": 2930187,
    "Capital": "Tirana",
    "Name": {
      "English": "Albania",
      "Arabic": "ألبانيا",
      "Chinese": "阿尔巴尼亚",
      "Franch": "Albanie",
      "Hindi": "अल्बानिया",
      "Korean": "알바니아",
      "Japanese": "アルバニア",
      "Russian": "Албания"
    }
  }
]
//script2.js
  var element = document.getElementById("idh1");
  element.innerHTML = countries[1].Code+" "+ countries[1].Continent;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="idh1"> Testsida</h1>

  </body>
  <script src="array.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

This works with your array when i run it in separate files. Don't know how to do that in the stackoverflow-editor so I just put them in the same file with comments!

Answer (score -1):

```js
//array.js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

//script2.js
var element = document.getElementById("idh1");
element.innerHTML = cars[1];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="idh1"> Testsida</h1>

  </body>
  <script src="array.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```

This works for me! If  it doesn't work for you it might be a problem that the document hasn't loaded. In that case try using a document ready function.